# Can't close Google Chrome app

Tags: process

I closed Google Chrome window, but it is still in TaskManager's process list and when I try to do "End Process" I get this:

[image]

What can cause this?

Comment: Try to force closing it with powershell. Open Powershell, then type the following: `Get-Process -ProcessName "chrome" | Stop-Process -Force`

Comment: I assume you have tried closing Task Manager and opening it back up and trying to end the process.  I sometimes see this, restarting Task Manager, fixes it for me

Comment: [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is a bit better at killing processes.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I am getting `Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "chrome". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.`

Comment: @Ramhound restarting Task Manager helped!